# MacOSX homebrew mysql root password

Tags: mysql, macos

For some reason MySQL stopped giving access for root. Uninstalled and reinstalled with Homebrew. Fresh install, fresh tables but when I enter

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get this error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I reinstalled MySQL five times but it is still asking for a password. How do I fix this?

Comment: There's almost an exact question in superuser. Follow these steps: http://superuser.com/a/400345

Comment: Just run `mysql_secure_installation` and answer the questions asked, simple

Comment: The mysql_secure_installation command prompts for a root password; if you've set and forgotten it, this procedure won't help.

Comment: If brew installed MySQL 5.7, follow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33924648/133106

Comment: FWIW `mysql -u root` worked here...

Comment: on macOS 10.13 user 'sudo mysql -u root' instead of 'mysql -u root'

Answer (score 200):

None of these worked for me. I think i already had mysql somewhere on my computer so a password was set there or something. After spending hours trying every solution out there this is what worked for me:

```
$ brew services stop mysql
$ pkill mysqld
$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/ # NOTE: this will delete your existing database!!!
$ brew postinstall mysql
$ brew services restart mysql
$ mysql -uroot
```

all credit to @Ghrua

Comment: the previous posts did not work for me, but this one while destructive worked great.

Comment: when you are logged into mysql eventually, use `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURNEWPASSWORD';` to set your new root password.

Comment: This worked for me without deleting my existing database

Comment: Finally a proper working solution. @2020 MacOs catalina.

Comment: None of the above proposed solutions worked for me but @Martin Braun's solution works. On Catelina, brewing mariadb sets up your user's account without password by default (not root!) So entering ```mysql``` without arguments logs in as (in my case) rvw@localhost.  At this moment you can assign a password to root using ```ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURNEWPASSWORD';```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I still get ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: This almost worked for me, what I did:

`brew services stop mysql; brew uninstall mysql; pkill mysqld; rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql; rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf; brew postinstall mysql; brew install mysql; brew services restart mysql; mysql -uroot`

Comment: (This answer worked in November 2023)
I installed mysql through their website and then brew.. (not remembering) .
This is what allowed me to run:
```mysql -u root```
without getting 
*Access denied for user 'root'@'local*
Everything else seems to be playing nice as well.

Answer (score 160):

Just run this command (where `NEWPASS` is your password):

```sh
$(brew --prefix mysql)/bin/mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASS
```

I have had the same error and fixed it this way.

Comment: Worked for me. Obviously (perhaps), the dollar sign ($) must be input as part of the command (it's not just a shell prompt).

Comment: This is the cleanest solution here. Just ensure that mySQL is running (if not, `mysql.server start`)

Comment: @BrentFoust Of course. I was disambiguating the usage of the `$` char at the beginning of a command line shell command. Others might be confused because the `$` sign is often used as a shell prompt marker on SO and other forums. But the lack of a space between the `$` and `(` should clue folks in as well.

Comment: I would recommend not including NEWPASS in the command to avoid storing in your shell's history file. That command will automatically ask for input if you run it without the pass so there's no reason to it. :)

Comment: Warning: /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: unknown variable 'loose-local-infile=1'
    /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
    error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: Doesn't work. I used `brew services mysql start` and I get an error `Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!`. It's already running.

Comment: I get the error `mysqladmin: unable to change password; error: 'File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)'`

Comment: if using mariadb: `$(brew --prefix mariadb)/bin/mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASS`

Comment: This works well for Maria DB as well - have an updoot.

Comment: Not working for me, with mariadb (even with @bryceadams note): /usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''

Comment: for mariadb, if you get access denied for user: `sudo $(brew --prefix mariadb)/bin/mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASS`

Answer (score 77):

In case you have inadvertently set and forgot the root password, and you don't want to wipe all your databases and start over because you are lazy and forgot to have a back up solution in place, and you are using a fairly recent Homebrew install (Winter 2013), here are steps to reset your password for MySQL.

**Stop the currently running MySQL instance**

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

**Now start mysql by hand skipping the grant tables and networking**

```
$(brew --prefix mysql)/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Note that if when you run **echo $(brew --prefix mysql)** and it does not respond as **"/usr/local/opt/mysql"** in bash, you will need to adjust the path accordingly.

Once you have done this, you now should have a running, unprotected MySQL instance up.

**Log in and set the password**

```
mysql -u root
```

At the prompt, enter the following MySQL command to set a new password for the effected user.

```
mysql> update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('new_password_here') WHERE user='root';
```

If all went to plan it should say:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Exit out of the MySQL prompt.

```
mysql> exit
Bye
```

Stop server:

```
mysqladmin -u root shutdown
```

Now, lets put back the launch daemon so we have our MySQL at the ready again:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Congratulations. You've just reset your mysql root password. Pour yourself a coffee and get a backup solution in place!

Comment: To stop the unprotected MySQL server after changing the password: `mysqladmin -u root shutdown`

Comment: I just ran into this problem, and found this answer to be the closest. I did notice that `password` was not a valid column in mysql 5.7.9. Instead I had to use `authentication_string` instead. The rest of the instructions worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: As M. Scott Ford said, the proper command is: `update user set authentication_string=password('new_password_here') where user='root';`

Comment: I had to run `update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('none') where user='root';` for it to work. (Like the comment right above me, but prepend `mysql.` to `user`.)

Comment: password function is removed since mysql 8.0.11. details [more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)

Comment: Column name has changed...  UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('xxxx!') WHERE User='root';

Answer (score 65):

I had the same problem a couple days ago. It happens when you install `mysql` via `homebrew` and run the initialization script (`mysql_install_db`) **before** starting the `mysql` daemon.

To fix it, you can delete `mysql` data files, restart the service and **then** run the initialization script:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm -r /usr/local/var/mysql/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

Comment: worked perfectly for me. I don't actually want to set a password for my local machine, so the other solutions aren't really what i'm looking for

Comment: mysql_install_db is deprecated, consider using `mysqld --initialize`

Comment: I just get `No such file or directory` when I run that first command.

Comment: after running mysqld --initialize command you will notice  in log message on console that it set temporary password for root user.. copy that and use password for next time you fire command "mysql -uroot -p"  -- It will definitely work .. and then mysql will ask you to reset the password .. check this out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: @VikrantLabde "It will definitely work" - very ambitious statement. I tried this, used the temporary password it gave me but it still did not grant access. Did you have to escape any of the punctuation with a backslash?

Answer (score 57):

Got this error after installing mysql via home brew.

So first remove the installation. Then Reinstall via Homebrew

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew install mysql
```

Then restart mysql service

```
 mysql.server restart
```

Then run this command to set your new root password.

```
 mysql_secure_installation
```

Finally it will ask to reload the privileges. Say yes. Then login to mysql again. And use the new password you have set.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. I'd already tried running `mysql_secure_installation` but the key part was the `mysql.server restart`

Comment: mysql_secure_installation was the key piece

Comment: To avoid the headache...just type use the restart command like nirojan says, then run mysql_secure_installation

Comment: This worked on Ventura 13.4.  Something got "configured" on reboot, and was able to continue with my work.  This should be added to the brew installer for ease of use.

Answer (score 33):

If you run on Mojave, Catalina, Big Sur and now on macOS Monterey:

```
brew install mariadb
...
brew services start mariadb
==> Successfully started `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)

 $(brew --prefix mariadb)/bin/mysqladmin -u root password newpass
/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''
```

also login with root account fails:

```
mariadb -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

then default admin user is created same name as your **MacOS** account **username**, e.g. *johnsmit*.

To login as root and set root password, issue (use *your* username):

```
mariadb -u johnsmit
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 17
Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ROOT-PASSWORD';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.006 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye
```

So you change root password form mysql on localhost.

Bonus: to change current or other user pass you can use `mysqladmin` command:

```
$(brew --prefix mariadb)/bin/mysqladmin -u arunas password 'newsecret'
```

but this does not affect localhost for some reason, but should work for app login.

Or use native MySQL change user password SQL, which explicitly specifies host, in my case 'localhost' account of the user:

```
mariadb -u arunas
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 11
Server version: 10.5.9-MariaDB Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'arunas'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newsecret';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.006 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye
```

Now let's try to login without password:

```
mariadb -u arunas
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'arunas'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

you see login failed, thus now we need specify the need of password:

```
mariadb -u arunas -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 13
Server version: 10.5.9-MariaDB Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye
```

Happy usage!

Comment: MacOS account name did it for me.

Comment: can I add a password for the macos account name user?

Comment: That works, but how to change root password?

Comment: same as any user shown example, but added instructions to change root password in one go on first login.

Comment: Finally some answer that did solve my problem!

Answer (score 12):

Since the question was asked/answered long time ago, those top answers do not work for me. Here's my solution, in 2020.

**Background**: Fresh mysql/mariadb installed by homebrew.

**Problem**: The password for root is not empty and unknown.

**The fix**:

1. mysql -u YOUR-SYSTEM-USERNAME -p
2. The password is empty (press enter)
3. ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD';
4. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

**The reason**:

1. Homebrew will create a user with root privileges named by the current MacOS username.
2. it has no password
3. Since it has all privileges, just reset the root password with that user.
4. The initial password for root was randomly generated.

Comment: 2020 correct answer. I can't get to ask for a password for the MacOS username

Comment: The above approach did not work. mysql_secure_installation worked for me on Catalina.

Comment: as of today, from high sierra to Catalina, brew install mariadb (mariadb: stable 10.6.4 (bottled).  I was able to do mysql -uroot -proot

Comment: This should be the top answer in 2023, for modern MacOS and the latest MariaDB from homebrew

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Comment: sudo did the trick

Comment: If you are running macOS Monterey 12.1 and have a fresh MariaDB installation with brew and want to acces mysql from the terminal this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

1. go to apple icon --> system preferences
2. open Mysql
3. in instances you will see "initialize Database"
4. click on that
5. you will be asked to set password for root --> set a strong password there
6. use that password to login in mysql from next time

Hope this helps.

Comment: Simple and easy way. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It finally worked for me. And don't forget to start server after above process. Its in same window as "initialize Database"

Answer (score 7):

Try with `sudo` to avoid the "Access denied" error:

`sudo $(brew --prefix mariadb)/bin/mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASS`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using macOS and install the MariaDB via Homebrew you can use the OS root password and then reset the password to whatever you want, in this case I removed the root's password:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password ''
```

or if you want to set a password you can put the password between the single quotations:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password 'NEW-PASSWORD-HERE'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on a fresh install on Mac. I installed MariaDB with:

```
brew install mariadb
```

Then started the service:

```
brew services start mariadb
```

I was unable to run 'mysql_secure_installation' as it prompted for the root password. Then I noticed in the install output:

```
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=jonny --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/ ....
```

So I tried logging in as the username specified in the mysql_install_db output and was successful e.g.

```
mysql -u jonny
```

Then at the mysql prompt if you want to set a password for the root user:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('ToPsEcReT');
```

Comment: So the information on this website is incorrect? , because it claims the `mysql_secure_installation` should work? 
 https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-1-16-on-mac-os-x-with-homebrew/

Comment: When I ran brew install mysql_install_db was triggered by brew. That blog post suggests running it manually. Maybe the brew procedure changed :shrug:

Comment: I just installed mariadb 10.5.6 on my mac, and was able to use `mariadb -u root` (without password)

Answer (score 2):

I've just noticed something common to most of the answers here, and confirmed on my fresh install. It's actually obvious if you look at the recommendations to run `mysqladmin -u root` without `-p`.

There is no password.

Brew sets mysql up with just a root user and no password at all. This makes sense, I guess, but the post-install Caveats don't mention it at all.

Comment: I had the access denied issue assuming no root password so I don't think the issue is obvious.

Comment: I'm not saying the issue is obvious; for anyone who has used MySQL under normal circumstances it's utterly confusing. But looking at the other responses, the reason is clear.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me for MAC https://flipdazed.github.io/blog/osx%20maintenance/set-up-mysql-osx

Start mysql by running

brew services start mysql

Run the installation script

mysql_secure_installation

You will be asked to set up a setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin. Enter y to do this.

Select the required password validation (Doesn’t really matter if it is just you using the database)

Now select y for all the remaining options: Remove anon. users; disallow remote root logins; remove test database; reload privileges tables.
Now you should receive a message of

`All done!`

Comment: to start mysql 5.7 use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573145/formula-mysql-is-not-installed?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Hopefully this works for you too!!!
Follow them.

```
brew services stop mysql
pkill mysqld
# NB: the following command will REMOVE all your databases!
# Make sure you have backups or SQL dumps if you have important data in them already.
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/
brew services restart mysql

mysql -uroot
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;

mysql -u root 
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password 
BY'YOUR_PASS_WORD!!!!';
```

Comment: You have to warn that, running `rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/` command will delete all databases and Mysql data on your computer!

Answer (score 1):

Running these lines in the terminal did the trick for me and several others who had the same problem.  These instructions are listed in the terminal after brew installs mysql sucessfully.

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents

cp /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'YOURPASSWORD'
```

where `YOURPASSWORD` is the password for root.

Comment: I just get `No such file or directory` when I run these commands

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have a  .my.cnf hiding in your homedir.  That was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The default password when you install mysql via brew is root try this, it worked for me

`mysql -uroot -proot`

Comment: From `brew info mysql`: We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run: mysql_secure_installation

Comment: @ssc The best way to set a password on a clean installation.

Answer (score 1):

So, in case someone has the same situation and configuration as I had and is also about to go mad - this worked for *me*.

After a long story I had a brew-installed MariaDB which kept automatically restarting when I killed its process (this was brew's doing), which *had* a root password, which I did *not* know.

`$ brew services list`

This shows something like:

`mariadb started jdoe /path/to/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist`

Stop the MySQL server with:

`$ brew services stop mariadb`

Then start it again **without** the root user (and not using brew):

`$ mariadbd --skip-grant-tables &`

Here, `mysql_secure_installation` did not work for me because of the `--skip-grant-tables`, and it would not work without the `--skip-grant-tables` because it needed the password (which I did not have).
Trying `$(brew --prefix mysql)/bin/mysqladmin -u root password hunter2` only returned strange errors and did nothing; `$(brew --prefix mariadb)/bin/mysqladmin -u root password hunter2` also didn't work, gave different errors, and suggestions that did not work for me.

But you *can* log into mysql now without credentials: `$ mysql`

Here, the old method of updating the user table for root doesn't work because "Column 'Password' is not updatable".
The new method uses `alter user` BUT only works *after* you have done `flush privileges;` so do that first.
Then:
`MariaDB [(none)]> alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'hunter2';`
(`MariaDB [(none)]>` is the MySQL prompt here)
Then do `flush privileges;` again.
Exit the MySQL client.

Now as far as brew is concerned, MariaDB is still not running, and so use `$ ps aux | grep -i mariadb` to find the pid and `$ kill -9 <pid>` it.
Then use `$ brew services start mariadb` to start it again.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this too and the solution was unironically to simply run this:

`mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Terminal 1:

```
$ mysql_safe
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Comment: This might have worked at the time the answer was posted, but broke in the meantime; with (current) MySQL version 5.7.21, it fails with ` Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'`.

Comment: UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('xxxxxx!') WHERE User='root';

Answer (score 0):

Iam using Catalina and use this **`mysql_secure_installation`** command and now works for me:

```
$ mysql_secure_installation
NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user. If you've just installed MariaDB, and
haven't set the root password yet, you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): << enter root here >>
```

i enter **`root`** as current password

```
OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Setting the root password or using the unix_socket ensures that nobody
can log into the MariaDB root user without the proper authorisation.
```

and do the rest

Answer (score 0):

For me, mysql was setup with a root user and no password.
I wanted to be able to login as my current user and not require the `-u root` bit. I used the following command to setup a super user:

```
mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER '$USER'@'localhost';"
mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$USER'@'localhost';"
mysql -u root -e "flush privileges;"
```

Any value for `$USER` will work.
I personally concatenated all the above with a semicolon but reformatted to make it hopefully easier for all to read.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the article from  @Roman Escart.
I guess the key is to use '$brew link --force mysql@5.7'
https://medium.com/macoclock/setup-mysql-in-a-specific-version-on-macos-35d8ad89c699

Answer (score 0):

login to DB as root :

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

you may run secure db as:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score -1):

Use init file to start mysql to change the root password.

```
brew services stop mysql
pkill mysqld
echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newRootPass';" > /tmp/mysql-init
$(brew --prefix mysql)/bin/mysqld --init-file=/tmp/mysql-init
```

Your root password is now changed. Make sure to **shutdown server properly** to save password change. In new terminal window execute

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

and enter your new pass.

Start your service and remove the init file

```
brew services start mysql
rm /tmp/mysql-init
```

Tested on mysql version 8.0.19

Answer (score -1):

***What is the easiest way to run Mysql on a Mac ?***

My solution was to install [MAMP](https://david.raleche.com/web-consulting/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-run-mysql-on-a-mac/).

https://www.mamp.info/en/mac/