# After fresh install of mysql, can't login without password

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed mysql on my mac (after never having it installed on this machine previously) using `brew install mysql`.  After the installation, I received this:

```
To connect:
    mysql -uroot
........
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mysql.server start
```

Great, it worked.  So I ran

```
kroe761$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
 SUCCESS! 
kroe761$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Wait, what?  I never gave mysql a password to begin with.  I tried using the sudo password, which didn't work (as expected).  I also tried using `-p` but then just hitting enter, with no password, but that did not work either.  So, how do I access mysql?

Edit:  I also tried this, which also did not work.

```
kroe761$ mysql.server start -skip-grant-tables
Starting MySQL
 SUCCESS! 
kroe761$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: mysql's root account has NOTHING to do with your system's root account. if you need to reset the root pw, then there's plenty of docs on the web on how to do that.

Comment: Yes, I assumed mysql's root password has nothing to do with my system's password.  Which is why I never expected sudo to work, just trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Disappointing that you made no mention of doing a [search here for the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access+denied+for+user+%27root%27%40%27localhost%27+%28using+password%3A+NO%29). You could at least show some effort to research the issue before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacOSX homebrew mysql root password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695362/macosx-homebrew-mysql-root-password)

Comment: Ken White - I googled for hours, and tried every solution I could find. Including the ones on the page that you linked (and I also linked in my solution below), and only 1 of them worked; but only after I used an edit of that solution. This is my first attempt at installing mysql, I forgot that everyone is a technical expert on SO. The judgment here is strong.

Answer (score -3):

After further googling, I found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878433/1535349

Note: I used `mysqld --initialize` for the last step, per the last comment.