# Unable to set MySQL password even after "mysqld --initialize" (homebrew)

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, macos-sierra

I understand this question has been asked many times on this forum, but I'm unable to log into the root for MySQL even after running `mysqld --initialize`, which sets a temporary password.

When I run mysql -uroot -p and enter the temporary password, I get:
`error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'`

I also tried: `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p` and setting the password this way but I got a similar error as above (except using password: YES)

What is my course of action?

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: 5.7.18 based on brew info mysql

Comment: have you tried using GUI?

Comment: what do you mean? Can you give further information/context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacOSX homebrew mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695362/macosx-homebrew-mysql-root-password)