# Formula `mysql` is not installed

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I'm trying to install mysql using `brew services start mysql` as per the website instructions but it gives me an error:

```
Formula `mysql` is not installed.
```

I already did a full uninstall on my XAMPP server.

Terminal:

```
Dylans-Macbook:~ dylandude$ brew install mysql@5.7
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
ansible                    jpeg-turbo                 phplint
ccrypt                     mapcrafter                 skinny
dxpy                       mikutter
jenkins-job-builder        pgcli

Warning: mysql@5.7 5.7.23 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 5.7.23, run `brew reinstall mysql@5.7`
Dylans-Macbook:~ dylandude$ brew services start mysql
Error: Formula `mysql` is not installed.
```

Comment: `brew install mysql`

Comment: @FrankerZ sorry, let me edit that post. I forgot to add that command

Answer (score 54):

You have installed the version 5.7 of MySQL with:

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```

So you have to start the service with:

```
brew services start mysql@5.7
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thanks, Ortomala!

Comment: Correct answer, it also worked for mariadb@10.3 after installing it. Thanks