# brew mysql is install but I get access denied on mac

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I am having serious problems to get up and running with mysql OSX.
I installed homebrew, php and supposedly mysql.

When I run brew services list, I see the following:

```
Name      Status  User   Plist
dnsmasq   started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mysql@5.7 started sidney /Users/sidney/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
nginx     started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php       started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
```

but once I try:

```
mysql -uroot
mysql -u root -p
```

They all give me the following error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I also tried:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

but I see the following in process of entering the password:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.
Enter password for user root:
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

How can I fix mysql on my mac?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacOSX homebrew mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695362/macosx-homebrew-mysql-root-password)

Comment: I have actually been searching for this since yesterday. The link you sent does not answer my question. Those commands don't work for me

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't meant to be rude. It would help others if you'd list what you already tried and what errors you got as result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695362/macosx-homebrew-mysql-root-password