# brew install mysql failing following this SO on mountain lion

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I followed this SO answer; [brew install mysql on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os)

At step 3 after typing in `mysql.server start` I get the following error;

`Starting MySQL 
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Oubliette.local.pid).`

I'm at a loss.. I've tried dozens of different suggestions found on the web and I just can't seem to get it to work..

Please any advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you install mysql using brew it will give you some instructions for the proper installation. I don't remember what that instructions are but you can find them by command `brew info mysql` or in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file) post.

Comment: Actually I had run that one a dozen times to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the issue.. apparently I had an old mysql.sock file that was causing collision on start.. Deleting that old .sock file removed the issue..