# Trouble installing MySQL on Osx Mountain Lion

Tags: mysql, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to brew install MySQL on Osx 10.8.3.

I've found some posts recommending using the dmg, but I need to use the mysql2 gem, and I've read that it is better to use brew.

I've tried everything from the top two answers here:

[brew install mysql on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os)

and tried [this tutorial](http://madebyhoundstooth.com/blog/install-mysql-on-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/), but I still get this error:

```
Starting MySQL.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Thomass-MacBook-Pro-5.local.pid).
```

MySQL still runs (I don't really understand why), but trying to create a database gives this error:

```
ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'asdf' (errno: 2)
```

I'm very much at a loss about what's going on, can anyone tell me what the issues here might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your database is either locked, or not started properly.  I would suggest checking the PID at (/usr/local/var/mysql/Thomass-MacBook-Pro-5.local.pid) and either kill the process through terminal or from the PID File itself.  As long as the PID is still there (whether it's asleep/zombied) you wouldn't be able to update/create a database.

You may also want to try rebooting your comp if you haven't done this step already.

Comment: Running mysql.server start produces the first error in my post. After deleting the .err file there is no /usr/local/var/mysql/Thomass-MacBook-Pro-5.local.pid file there

Comment: Ah, after 5 hours on this today, it was the reboot that fixed it.