# Removing mysql using launchctl

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, uninstallation, launchd

I am trying to uninstall my old sql so that I can install a new one. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378429/602524) post but stuck at `launchctl unload`.

`[~/Library/LaunchAgents]$ ls` `com.adobe.ARM.202f4087f2bbde52e3ac2df389f53a4f123223c9cc56a8fd83a6f7ae.plist`
`com.mysql.mysqld.plist`
`com.facebook.videochat.ava.plist`
`homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Users/ava/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist"): No such file or directory
nothing found to unload`

Why is not able to find the file when it is there?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `launchctl unload homebrew.mxcl.postgresql`

Comment: I ran that from home dir.

Comment: Search for homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist file in your mac

Comment: @ParagBafna The location is shown in the question, there's no issue there.

Comment: Couldn't stat("/Users/ava/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist"): No such file or directory nothing found to unload

Comment: @ava I mean run it without the full path. Once loaded into `launchctl` it doesn't use paths.

Comment: `launchctl: Couldn't stat("homebrew.mxcl.postgresql"): No such file or directory`
nothing found to unload

Comment: launchctl list  and check  for homebrew.mxcl.mysql

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check for homebrew.mxcl.mysql

```
launchctl list
```

Remove

```
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.mysql
```

Answer (score -2):

Try use this command so solve your problem:

> $ brew services stop mysql

Comment: ```brew service stop mysql 
Error: Unknown command: service```

Comment: @argoden You have wrong spell of services. You should add "s" to it. Anyway you can try copy then paste.