# Can't fully uninstall MYSQL with Homebrew with Mac 10.8.5 How to find/remove "/etc/my.cnf" from old install?

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, homebrew

This is a sample from my terminal.

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ My$ brew update
Already up-tåo-date.
My-MacBook-Pro:~ My$ brew uninstall mysql
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql
My-MacBook-Pro:~ My$ brew install mysql
Warning: Your Xcode (4.5.2) is outdated
Please install Xcode 4.6.3.
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/mysql-5.6.1
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.6.13.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mysql-5.6.13.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

To connect:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13: 9381 files, 354M
My-MacBook-Pro:~ My$
```

The caveat says there is a left over file from another install, but I can't seem to uninstall it. I am not very familiar with libraries (though i look forward to getting better at them), and I can't find where all these files live.

I tried searching for my.cnf, but the results were:

```
adodb-mysqli.inc.php
adodb-mysqli.inc.php
php_CORE3.xml
```

none of which appear to be the right thing.

This also might be relevant.

When I enter in my terminal:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

I get this, which contradicts what I was led to believe I would see.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export Parth=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/$
```

Any ideas on how I can remove this rogue file?

Edit: Further attempts listed below. They all remain fruitless.

I tried searching for the file in my terminal by entering the following:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ My$ sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
My-MacBook-Pro:~ My$ locate my.cnf
My-MacBook-Pro:~ My$ sudo find /etc -name *.cnf
```

No results.

I tried following the top two answers here: [brew install mysql on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os)

but the file is still present. Both these (mentioned in the top answer) resulted in "no such file or directory"

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

I have also read that homebrew does not install a my.cmf file. This is all very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i checked [this brew definition for mysql](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mysql.rb#L138) and it appears that this message is always displayed; no matter what.

So I guess you can ignore it if you are sure there is no `my.cnf` around.

Comment: Well that certainly changes my issue. Its been driving me nuts. Thank you. 

I guess I have a different issue then. I suppose I will make a new post about then. I assumed that caveat was what was causing me problems because when I try to connect by using 'mysql -uroot' in the terminal, I get the error:

'MyMac$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'