# RoR 4 ERROR on 'rake db:create' or 'rake about'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have RoR 4.0 and ruby-1.9.3-p484 installed. `gem install bundler` and `bundle install` run without any errors. Then I need to create a db using `rake db:create` and I'm getting following error (I get the same error on `rake about` as well):

> rake aborted! Could not load
>   'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the
>   adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other
>   than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary
>   adapter gem to the Gemfile.

**From `gem list`:**
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
mysql2 (0.3.14)
rake (10.1.1, 0.9.2.2)

**config/database.yml**
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
host: localhost
database: my_database
pool: 20
username: root
password: 
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

MySQL is running

Please let me know if I should share some more informaion. Thank you!!!

Comment: show an output of `bundle list|grep sql`

Comment: Check that your Gemfile includes a line with `gem 'mysql2'`

Comment: Gemfile sure does have gem 'mysql2' line.

Comment: bundle list|grep sql: 
* mysql2 (0.3.14)

Comment: try to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` (and I hope you use some ruby manager, such as rvm, rbenv,...)

Comment: I get exact same error Gotva. I do use rvm.

Comment: what is `activerecord-mysql2-adapter`? it looks like not supported any more ([last commit a year ago](https://github.com/kronn/activerecord-mysql2-adapter)). Try to remove it (do not forget to run `bundle install` after it ;) )

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: hmmm... very strange. Examine your `Gemfile.lock` you should have two lines with `mysql2`: 1. "mysql2" 2. "mysql2 (0.3.14)" - is it so? And try to run `bundle update mysql2`

Comment: That's exactly the case. Updating the gem didn't help either.

Comment: I'm getting exact same error trying to run anything with rake. rake, rake about, rake db:create, rake db:migrate...

Comment: one more idea: maybe your gemset is broken - try to create a new one (or remove/cleanup existed) and install gems there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your suggestions! I finally found the solution.

Apparently, mysql2 gem did not work well with mysql-5.5.12. It was also installed from source files on my mac. I deleted mysql from my machine and installed it using Brew following steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os). Everything seems fine now.