# homebrew: MySQL not starting, Can't update PID file

Tags: mysql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I am a new Mac user and trying to set up the development environment with Apache, PHP and MySQL. Initially, after a lot of installs and reinstalls i succeeded in installing MySQL (Apache and PHP came bundled with Mac) but now again mysql refuses to start up and gives the error, `The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Nikhils-MacBook-Pro.local.pid)`.

I have literally gone through entire SO questions regarding this problem but have not found a way to fix this and i mean i have done everything to start this but in vain. I have created the PID file too but it disappears in moments, i did a cleanup and reinstall using this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os/6378429#6378429) but it has failed **YET** again. Please, i need to get my server started, i am really losing on to serious work and time.

Is there any other miraculous way to fix this unattainable feat? Also, if anyone asks what is the error in the log files, please don't as there is no log being registered as the server hasn't started yet.

Comment: Could you try tracing the MySQL startup with `sudo dtruss -f <startup_script>`?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got a similar problem with MySQL on a Mac (Mac Os X Could not startup MySQL Server. Reason: 255 and “ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file”) and after a long trial and error process, finally in order to restore the file permissions, I’ve just do that:

- launch the Disk Utilities.app
- choose my drive on the left panel
- click on the “Repair disk permissions” button

This did the trick for me. Hoping this can help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

[brew install mysql on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os)

These instructions helped me.  There was a my.cnf in /usr/local/opt/mysql/  which seems to have been the problem for me.  YMMV.