# MySQL Error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded

Tags: mysql, macos, macos-high-sierra

I just installed MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22 with Homebrew on my macOS v10.13.4.
I ran the command:
`brew install mysql`

After the installation completed, as directed by Homebrew, I ran the command:
`mysql_secure_installation`
and was returned the error: `Error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found`

I tried a few things like changing default_authentication_plugin to mysql_native_password in the my.cnf file but it still throws the same error.

Next I tried running:
`mysql_upgrade -u root`
and I was thrown the same error again `mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2059: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question might better be asked on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179516/sequel-pro-and-mysql-connection-failed/ helped me basically Sequal Pro couldn't handle the new password, reverting the type of mysql-password engine to "old way" solved it for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found the running process of mysqld by `sudo lsof -i tcp:3306` then I killed it using `sudo kill -9 <PID>`.

After this I tried `mysql_secure_installation` again, but ran into a new error :

> Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)

After trying a few fixes for getting mysql.sock to work, I started the MySQL server with `sudo mysql.server start` then went ahead with `mysql_secure_installation` to set password for the root user.

This worked for me finally.

> Note: Homebrew asks you to first do `mysql_secure_installation` before starting the MySQL server for the first time but that just made me run into endless loop of errors.

Comment: If you can't get this to work, save yourself a lot of frustration and just install mariadb. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/ Worked first time

Answer (score 0):

Restart the mysql server to take the changes in affect and try connecting via mysql with any mysql client.

Otherwise use docker

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -d mysql --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
mysql -uroot --protocol tcp
```

[Try in PWD](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/?stack=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GitHub30/docs/change-default_authentication_plugin/mysql/stack.yml)

Related a question.

[Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Comment: There is no mysql server running right now. The mysql_secure_installation is throwing this error. I have already tried every answer in the link you have included.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this should be an issue with the mysql version installed. Just as above you should first find then kill the mysqld process attached on port 3306

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:3306
sudo kill -9 <Peocess ID>
```

Then upgrade the mysql installation via brew, in this case:

```
brew upgrade mysql
```

This should solve it.Running mysql after the upgrade should start your server after the installation.

e.g `mysql -u root -p [your password here]`