# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied mysql 5.7 macos

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to reset my password in Mysql for five hours now.  When I write:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I should also add that my MySql server is running according to system preferences.

When I try the solutions on mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080366/mac-mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

which says to try

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
```

I can't do that because there is no such path on my computer.  And in the folder /usr/local/mysql/bin/ there is no file called mysqladmin

That site also recommends

```
Select System Preferences... from the Apple  menu and click the Network app to launch it as shown below.
Click your Wi­Fi connection to select it
Click the Advanced... option
Click the Proxies tab to select it
Check the top 3 options Auto Proxy Discovery Automatic Proxy Configuration Web Proxy (HTTP)
Click OK.
Click Apply.
Quit System Preferences.
```

But that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

for reset password for mysql user root as follows:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password')  WHERE  User='root';
```

Comment: That solution would not have worked for me because I couldn't place the command into any input box.  But I solved the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GeVMDQsDpc) I was able to solve the problem.

I stopped the mysql server then input

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

I then got this output

```
2022-07-26T06:19:17.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Admins-MacBook-Pro-4.local.err'.
2022-07-26T06:19:17.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Admins-MacBook-Pro-4.local.err'.
2022-07-26T06:19:17.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
```

which also turned the mysql server back on.  That's all it took.