# Conflicting MySQL installations with Homebrew

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql2

1) I originally installed the latest version of mysql (5.7.11) using homebrew.

2) I then also installed mysql56 using homebrew

3) I then uninstalled the original mysql homebrew install

brew search mysql currently returns a check only next to 56=>

automysqlbackup
   homebrew/versions/mysql55
   mysql
   mysql-cluster
   homebrew/versions/mysql51
   homebrew/versions/mysql56 ✔

4) If I start a mysql console I get the following:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 33
Server version: 5.7.11 Homebrew
```

5) Running `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` returns

```
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                 |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.11                |
| protocol_version        | 10                    |
| slave_type_conversions  |                       |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 |
| version                 | 5.7.11                |
| version_comment         | Homebrew              |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                |
| version_compile_os      | osx10.11              |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

6) mysql> SELECT VERSION();

```
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.11    |
+-----------+
```

7) However, mysql --version returns

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.29, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I believe I am having some mysql compatibility issues and need to be running 5.6.29, is there a way to verify that I am running 5.6?

Answer (score 0):

Running `ps auxww | grep mysql` should give you the full path to the mysql you're actually running. Then you can do `ls -l /usr/local/path/to/mysql` which should show you the link into the directory with the version you're running. Should look something like `../Cellar/mysql/version/myversion`.

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378429/2009203) might be helpful too.