# Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've looked through a few of the many posts on this, and I think my problem might even have a simpler solution, but I'm not sure what it is. If there's a solution for me out there that I haven't managed to be find, I apologize, and I'm happy to get a link to another post. :)

The interesting thing is that I DO have a file at `/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib`, so I figure I have the wrong version of MySQL, or something similar to that.

I'm just starting to work on the code, and it isn't my project so it would be easier for me to adjust my MySQL installation than to change the gems and such, if possible.

Any thoughts on how to get Rails to recognize my `libmysqlclient`?

Some background info: I'm on a Mac with a fresh installation of MySQL via Homebrew. I get this error when trying to start a `rails server`. The mysql2 gem version is 0.3.14

Comment: version of Rails and mysql ?

Comment: Rails version 4.0.10 and the MySQL version was 5.7.x, but I switched to 5.6.29, and now everything is working! For any future reference, this SO post helped me a out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os, just change "mysql" to "mysql56" where it's necessary