# Installing mysql through terminal

Tags: mysql

I am having some issues getting sql to work when trying to set my rails project. I have the latest version of both ruby and rails, the issue I believe lies within my terminal PATH. When typing gem install mysql, I get the following error:

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied @
>   rb_sysopen -
>   /Users/myName/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/COPYING.

And when echoing my PATH I get the following description: 
/Users/myName/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin 
This is a messed up path, and yes I have specified the PATH I want in the .bash_profile. My desired path looks like this: 
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"` It just doesn't seem to work. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Running Sierra on a Macbook Pro 2015.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue with the help of this thread: [brew install mysql on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os). And with using my brain a bit more and installing the lated command tools... Hope this can help someone else who may have forgotten Xcodes part in it all.

Answer (score 0):

That error doesn't look like anything to do with your `$PATH`, which looks OK. It seems that you're trying to write to `/Users/myName/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/COPYING` but don't have permission. Maybe you installed something as root, and now root owns the gem files.

My guess is you need to fix the ownership of your `.rbenv` directory.

Try `sudo chown -R myName /Users/myName/.rbenv`, or if you want to be more rigorous, `ls -l /Users/myName/.rbenv` and see what the permissions look like before fixing whichever need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chris. I tried using the first command you gave me and got a long list of different paths that all ended with: "Operation not permitted". So for example: chown: /Users/myName/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/.gemtest: Operation not permitted

Comment: Then `sudo chown -R myName /Users/myName/.rbenv`

Comment: I should have seen that... So this seemed to work with getting the permission out of the way. But now when trying to install mysql, "gem install mysql" I still get an error. Will try to reinstall rbenv.

Comment: Hello again! So I tried installing rbenv again and I get these errors: "Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew." I have received these errors before and tried deleting them, ran "brew update", but now they seem to be here again. Any tips?

Comment: Now you're trying to alter system paths as a non-root user. Are you trying to make a system-wide installation or a personal one? If system-wide, do the whole thing as root. If personal, make sure the installation doesn't want to make links in `/usr/local/`

Comment: It will be system-wide. But there seems to be a deeper underlying issue when installing rbenv.