# Will the MAMP(PRO) mysql conflict with brew install mysql on macos

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, homebrew, mamp

I'm trying to install a clean mysql on my macos Sierra. As I already installed **brew**, I decided to use this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os). Nevertheless, before installation, these pre-install check is done:

1. I have already checked the bash line with **mysql** command, and found no such command.
2. I `brew info mysql`, and found mysql **Not Installed**.
3. However, I still have doubt over that I might not have a clean installation environment. So I use the `find / -name mysql -type d` to search all the directory for **mysql**. And I've found there are mysql included in MAMP. As these line writes:

   ```
   /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
   /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql
   /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/mysql
   /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/DBD/mysql
   ```

I've installed MAMP about two years ago. Now I just want to learn mysql in command line rather than one-click environment like MAMP. And I wonder **if I can install the mysql using brew to get a generic mysql environment if I don't uninstall the MAMP?** And **WHY** is that the MAMP will/will not affect the mysql installed from brew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, they wont' be on conflict.

Mamp use another port, and brew use default mysqm port 3306

Mamp use this foder: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql

Brew use his own folder :  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/(version...)

with brew you don't need use path to execute bin files, just type 'mysql -uroot -p' on the terminal.

Comment: That explains my doubt. So they are actually installed in different places. With homebrew, mysql is installed in the environmental path so it can be executed without a path.

Comment: but how to specify the cersion to other programs