# How to install and start MySQL 5.7 on macOS BigSur (Apple Silicon) with Homebrew?

Tags: mysql, homebrew, mysql-5.7, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I need a specific version of MySQL (5.7) to be installed on my MacBook with M1.

I'm trying to do that with Homebrew.

`brew install mysql@5.7`

The output:

```
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

mysql@5.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew, because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have mysql@5.7 first in your PATH, run:   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find mysql@5.7 you may need to set:   export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/lib"   export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/include"


To have launchd start mysql@5.7 now and restart at login:   brew services start mysql@5.7 Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:   /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql.server start
```

Right after that, I try to run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source .zshrc
mysql_secure_installation
```

And get the error:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.
Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Also, I've tried:
`brew services start mysql@5.7`

And also get the error:

```
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/vivanc/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
```

Seems like there is a permissions-related problem.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, tried cleaning everything and reinstalling MySQL but still no luck

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66618600/16939495) answer from Daniel Tovesson worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

If you are running into issues like "`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'`" or "`The post-install step did not complete successfully MySQL`", and you installed a previous version of mysql (e.g. 8.x) previously, you may have been at the point where you need to clean everything before reinstalling your preferred version of mysql@x.x.

If you've already visited these to links:
[Uninstall all those broken versions of MySQL and re-install it with Brew on Mac Mavericks (Coderwall)](https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks) + [Install MySQL 5.7 on macOS using Homebrew (github)](https://gist.github.com/operatino/392614486ce4421063b9dece4dfe6c21) and your're still having trouble with starting your mysql-service, you should try to also remove also `/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf` file.

Remove it together with all the related files too! **Summary for an M1 Apple Silicon machine**, after uninstalling via `brew uninstall mysql` or `brew uninstall mysql@x.x`, please remove:

```
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
```

After this, everything worked like a fresh install (for me). Hope this saved someone's time.

Comment: I had the same issues, it was just a conflict between MySQL 8 and 5.7. I uninstalled both, then reinstalled 5.7 again and it worked

Comment: Within the Apple Silicon M1 this solution is enough and works fine for the native/latest version of `mysql` but for different versions like `mysql@5.7` it's needed to follow @seemly solution:
edit `my.cnf` then append `tmpdir` and `user` to it.

Comment: This worked for me on Apple Silicon M1.

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 15):

While this question is specific to Apple Silicon and mysql 5.7, and I will address that in this answer, I would like to start by adding some general notes to save others time:

Homebrew supports mysql 5.7 for both intel and apple silicon.
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mysql@5.7

Homebrew supports mysql 5.6 for the intel chip, but not apple silicon:
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mysql@5.6

If you need 5.6 on apple silicon, it's probably a good idea to just settle with 5.7 since production will need to be upgraded eventually and the differences aren't that big.

In my situation I originally did `brew install mysql` and it gave me the latest mysql (currently 8.0). When I tried going back over it and doing `brew install mysql@5.6`, of course this didn't work due to not being supported on the m1 max (apple silicon). I ran into issues then trying to get `brew install mysql@5.7` working. I followed some guides mentioning various suggestions. After playing with it for a while, it seems that running two versions of mysql at once will corrupt your mysql files and make it hard to work with and confuse homebrew.

I came across these guides:
[brew install mysql on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-macos)
https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/brew+uninstall+mysql

Before reading further, note that in my situation, I had a zip available for my whole local mysql database needs and could risk destroying what I have.

Warning! Reading further and executing these commands carelessly may delete your mysql storage. Make sure you have a backup.

`brew remove mysql` is a good command that got rid of my latest install.
I also needed `brew remove mysql@5.7` even though this is the version I'm trying to install, but they were stepping on each other's foot...

`brew cleanup` is nice, I noticed it freed up some lock files.

I don't recall having any luck with:
`launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`
but you can try it.

`rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` has worked for me.
But note there will also be another file in there for your 5.7 setup.
I'd recommend:
`cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents/` then look around to see if you have any mysql* in there. Then if you do, such as `homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist`, then remove it.

These are some that worked for me:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.default
```

Also:

```
cd opt/homebrew/var
```

Then if you notice a mysql directory in there, remove it.

It's possible you might have docker or something else similar also running mysql or mysqld.
`ps -ax | grep "[m]ysql"`
(Note the brackets and quotes in the above is to prevent the grep from showing up in the process list and matching itself unlike the lazier version: `ps -ax | grep mysql` which will give the impression there's an extra mysql process running)

Once you're ready, please run:
`brew services list`
double-check you don't have mysql in there.
Then double check you don't have any mysql process running:
`ps -ax | grep "[m]ysql"`
This can happen for example if you enter `mysqld` for example....
You might need to do `brew services stop mysql` or `brew services stop mysql@5.7` or similar and repeat steps if you see anything on the service list or process list.

Finally, you should be ready for a fresh install.
The fresh installation process should be rather straight forward:

```
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
brew services start mysql@5.7
```

Then run `brew services list` to make sure your installation worked correctly.
If you see it's green and "started", your installation was successful!

You should also run:
`mysql_secure_installation`
Then choose a password for root and go through the list of questions like validation, etc.

Once you're installed, you might also run into mysql mode issues.
`cd /opt/homebrew/etc` and you should find a my.cnf file.
Edit it using either vim or nano.
You should see something like:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Edit it and set the mysql mode. For example, I don't want the no_zero_in_date mode, so I use:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Then restart mysql like so:
`brew services restart mysql@5.7`

Then double check you still have a green status "started":
`brew services list`
If you do, then you should have the no_zero_in_date mode disabled.
You can test it with a query:
`SELECT @@sql_mode;`

You should now have mysql 5.7 running on Apple Silicon and have the sql_mode set.

If you run into more troubleshooting, do your best to get into a known state such as uninstalled, doing a fresh install, or already installed with some version, etc.

Comment: This is working for me. You're a life saver. Thanks.

Comment: This is working for me. Spent hours trying other ways. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it after hours of searching, it was because I had not cleaned everything regarding my previous MySQL 8.X installation. I followed [this](https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks) and got suspicious when I realized I don't have most of the folders there. I then did a search for all folders named `mysql` on my computer and found a `mysql` folder in `opt/homebrew/var`. After removing it, reinstalling MySQL 5.7, and starting the server everything is working as expected.

Comment: So, now you can start/stop MySQL server using `brew services start mysql@5,7` without any permissions errors? I have these errors without any previously installed MySQL on fresh macOS.

Comment: Yes that is correct, maybe we didn't have the same issue then

Comment: but /opt/homebrew/var/mysql contains the table data! I can't delete that.

Answer (score 5):

When setting up my Apple M1 Macbook Pro I was experiencing the issue of the following error message being thrown:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

My fix was to modify the MySQL config file:

```
nano /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

Append the following lines:

```
tmpdir=/tmp
user=root
```

Then run:

```
brew services restart mysql@5.7
```

This fixed my issue, and I was then able to connect successfully with my DB client.

Comment: In my case (mysql@5.7 and macOS Monterey 12.2.1) `my.cnf` file was in `/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf`.
Within the Apple Silicon M1 if we remove mysql installation and just install the latest version with `brew install mysql` it will perfectly work but with a different version like `mysql@5.7` it's needed to append the two lines to the file `my.cnf`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found the solution (or workaround).

After installing the MySQL 5.7 with Homebrew just run:

```
mysql.server start
```

MySQL is started and then you are able to run `mysql_secure_installation` and `mysql` commands.

Answer (score 1):

I got this warning:

```sh
You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1
```

I run those two command then it works.